# Perl - Concatenating SQL Results in CSV File

Tags: sql, perl, concatenation, string-concatenation, export-to-csv

I'm querying a database for two columns and writing them to a .csv file. The issue I am having is the line of code below is causing this error: "Use of uninitialized value in string at line 105".

```
print $file "$hash_ref->{'UserNM'}" . join("\t", "$hash_ref->{'EventDT'}" . "\n");
```

What I am looking for is something like this in the file:

```
User ID    Last Login TimeStamp
user12     2012-12-27 12:21:12
user49     2011-06-13 12:21:12
user43     2010-09-15 12:21:12
user09     2013-01-07 12:21:12
user87     2012-08-12 12:21:12
user38     2013-01-07 12:21:12
user31     2009-04-30 12:21:12
```

Just ask if more code is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simplify the concatenation and pass the columns through as variables using the following code:

```
    my $usernm = "$row->{'UserNM'}";
    my $logindt = "$row->{'EventDT'}";

    # dump users and last login timestamp into file
        print MYFILE "$usernm \t $logindt \n";
```

In my opinion, this is much simpler and cleaner. And it works. Anyone disagree?

Answer (score 2):

One of your hash values are not defined. Try this:

```
printf $file "%s\t%s\n", $hash_ref->{'UserNM'} // q{}, $hash_ref->{'EventDT'} // q{};
```

It will default to an empty string (`q{}`) if the value is undefined.

Comment: This will also provide the empty string if one of the values is zero (0). On newer perls (5.10+), the defined-or `//` can be used instead.

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at line 107.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at line 107.
Argument "<no user>" isn't numeric in division (/) at line 107.
Illegal division by zero at line 107. Also, using the original || fails to write the second column.

Comment: @AndersonNicholasL, it sounds like you have `/` instead of `//`.

Comment: printf $file "%s\t%s\n", $hash_ref->{'UserNM'} || q{}, $hash_ref->{'EventDT'} || q{}; returns the correct information for one column and fails to write the second column. printf $file "%s\t%s\n", $hash_ref->{'UserNM'} // q{}, $hash_ref->{'EventDT'} // q{}; returns the error shown above.

Comment: @AndersonNicholasL, which version of perl are you using? If it is before 5.10, you need to use `||` since `//` would not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

As @gpojd pointed out, one of the hash refs is not defined. You could also include an `IFNULL/ISNULL` statement for each of the fields in the query which might return `NULL` to just set them to blank.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this still isn't working for you.  It may be instructive for your debugging purposes to check if both $hash_ref->{'UserNM'} and $hash_ref->{'EventDT'} are defined prior to attempting to print them.  This will allow you to give each variable a fallback default value and at least let you analyze some output.

```
my $UserNM;
my $EventDT;

if (defined($hash_ref->{'UserNM'})) {
    $UserNM = $hash_ref->{'UserNM'};
} else {
    $UserNM = "default username";
}

if (defined($hash_ref->{'EventDT'})) {
    $EventDT= $hash_ref->{'EventDT'};
} else {
    $EventDT= "default event date";
}

print $file "$UserNM" . join("\t", "$EventDT" . "\n");
```